# Perl: Make thread sleep

Tags: multithreading, perl, sleep

I have a basic Perl script that runs a function with 20 threads.

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Queue;
use File::Slurp;

$| = 1; my $numthreads = 20;

my $fetch_q   = Thread::Queue->new();
sub fetch {
    while ( my $target = $fetch_q->dequeue() ) {
        my $request = `curl "http://WEBSITE" -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}"`; # Returns HTTP Status code of request (i.e. 200, 302, 404, etc)
        if ($request eq "200") {
            print "Success. Sleeping for 5 seconds.";
            sleep(5);
        }
        else {
            print "Fail. Will try again in 10 seconds.";
            sleep(10);
            redo;
        }
    }
}

my @workers = map { threads->create( \&fetch ) } 1 .. $numthreads;
$fetch_q->enqueue( 1 .. $max );
$fetch_q->end();
foreach my $thr (@workers) {$thr->join();}
```

If a condition is true, I want the *thread* to sleep for 5 seconds but have all the other threads continue. Right now when I use `sleep(5)` it seems like the entire script sleeps for 5 seconds.

How can I use `sleep()` for individual threads?

Comment: `cond_timedwait` in `threads::shared` looks promising.

Comment: what OS is this for?

Comment: Windows but I have cygwin installed.

Comment: So which one are you using, Windows (`perl -v` says `built for MSWin32-...`) or cygwin (`built for built for cygwin-...`)?

Comment: Is "CONDITION" true for all threads, or for at least `$max` threads?  Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @pilcrow: Updated original post with MCVE. Essentially, if status code of curl request to my site is `200`, then it is a success and will wait 5 seconds before trying again. Otherwise, it is a fail and the thread will wait 10 seconds before trying again. `Sleep()` makes the whole process sleep, not just the thread. I am trying to just make the individual thread sleep

Comment: This is a syntax error `if $enter eq "200" {` .. there should be parentheses around the condition in an `if` statement. Also, `$enter` is not defined.

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Fixed

Answer (score 3):

`sleep` is the right tool. I don't know why you think it seems to block all threads, but it doesn't. The following illustrates this:

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;

use Thread::Queue;

my $fetch_q = Thread::Queue->new();

sub fetch {
    while (defined( my $job = $fetch_q->dequeue() )) {
        if ($job) {
            print threads->tid, " Starting to sleep\n";
            sleep(5);
            print threads->tid, " Finished sleeping\n";
        }
        else {
            print threads->tid, " Starting to sleep\n";
            sleep(10);
            print threads->tid, " Finished sleeping\n";
        }
    }
}

my @workers = map { threads->create( \&fetch ) } 1 .. 2;
$fetch_q->enqueue($_) for 0, 1, 1;
$fetch_q->end();
foreach my $thr (@workers) {$thr->join();}
```

Output:

```
1 Starting to sleep
2 Starting to sleep
2 Finished sleeping
2 Starting to sleep   <-- The second job picked up work while the first was still sleeping.
1 Finished sleeping
2 Finished sleeping
```